# How do I install php in unattended mode in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, php

I am trying to install php in unattended mode. That is, install php using pkg install without having to be prompted for location. Maybe there is an environment variable that must be set or something?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The prompt is being caused by tzdata. To stop it from prompting I just need to execute

> export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

Before running apt install. I can just set the timezone after installation.